# Stochastic exponential of Ito procss local martingale iff the Ito process is

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, local-martingales

Let $dX_t= \mu_t dt + \sigma_t d B_t$ be an Ito process and define its stochastic exponential by

$$\mathscr E X_t= e^{\int_0^t \mu_s ds + \int_0^t \sigma_s dB_s - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^t \sigma_s^2 ds} $$

> Show that $\mathscr E X_t$ is a local martingale iff $X_t$ is a local
>   martingale

I was able to show that
$$d \mathscr E X_t = \mathscr E X_t d X_t$$ using Itos formula. For the first direction, if $X$ is a local martingale, then it has no drift and
$$\mathscr E X_t=1+\int_0^t \sigma_s \mathscr E X_s d B_s$$
using almost sure continuity of $e^{x}$ gives us boudnedness on $[0,t]$ and we show easily that
$$\int_0^t \sigma_s^2(\omega) \mathscr E X_s(\omega)^2 ds <\infty $$
for almost all $\omega$. 
But I have no idea how to show the other direction.

Comment: Write Itô's formula for the logarithm?

Comment: I did, and then what?

Comment: The same as other direction,  no?

Comment: not really? I dont have the form of the exponential as an ito process. I know that in general the integral against a local martingale is a local martingale but that is way too general. There should be a simpler reasoning here.

Comment: In the case I did, I reduced it to an integral against brownian motion, which we know is a local martingale for adapted L^2 processes

Comment: Well, maybe taking logarithm is not needed indeed. What is needed is that an Itô process is a local martingale iff the drift is zero.

Comment: Ya that gives me one direction that I showed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You showed $d\mathcal{E}(X)_t = \mathcal{E}(X)_tdX_t$, and since $X$ is an Ito process you have $d X_t = \mu_t dt + \sigma_t dB_t$ so substituting in we have $d\mathcal{E}(X)_t = \mathcal{E}(X)_t \mu_t dt + \mathcal{E}(X)_t \sigma_t dB_t$.  An Ito process is a local martingale iff the drift term is $0$, so $\mathcal{E}(X)_t \mu_t =0$ for all $t$.  Since $e^x \ne 0$ for all real $x$, $\mathcal{E}(X)_t \ne 0$ so $\mathcal{E}(X)_t \mu_t =0$ implies $\mu_t = 0$ and therefore $dX_t = \sigma_t dB_t$.  Since we showed $dX_t$ has no drift term, we conclude $X_t$ is a local martingale.

Comment: Indeed, how did I miss that!

Comment: I forgot to award the bounty, apologies.